# How to include extreme in Pandas IntervalIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate an `IntervalIndex` with intervals closed on the right-side, but with the first interval also closed on the left-side. Something like: `[[0, 0.4], (0.4, 0.6], (0.6, 1]]`.
But I am not able to create such an `IntervalIndex`: the various methods to construct an `IntervalIndex` accept a `closed` option that specifies how all intervals should be closed, but it is not possible to specify a different closure for the extreme intervals:

```py
breaks = [0, 0.4, 0.6, 1]
In: pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(breaks, closed="right")
Out: IntervalIndex([(0.0, 0.4], (0.4, 0.6], (0.6, 1.0]],
                   closed='right',
                   dtype='interval[float64]')
```

I think this should be possible since `pd.cut` function has an `include_lowest` option that does exactly that (I assume that `pd.cut` creates an `IntervalIndex` under the hood, am I right?). But I cannot use `pd.cut` directly with the `breaks` list: I need an `IntervalIndex` object. I need to preserve the exact `IntervalIndex` that is used by `pd.cut`.

I have tried creating an `IntervalIndex` directly from `Interval` objects:

```py
pd.IntervalIndex([pd.Interval(0, 0.4, closed="both"),
                  pd.Interval(0.4, 0.6, closed="right"),
                  pd.Interval(0.6, 1, closed="right")
                  ])
```

but I get `ValueError: intervals must all be closed on the same side`.

I was able to find a workaround for my problem: using `-0.0001` instead of `0` in my `breaks` list, so that, even though the first interval is open on the left, it actually includes `0`. But this is a very hacky solution, in my opinion! Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick if you want to include 0 and do not expect values below zero is to set something slightly lower than 0 as the left bound, like -0.01.

Comment: I realize you added this as edit. If your data really has no negative values, I think this is a fine solution